"Multiple root tags" and "Top level element is not completed" error in AndroidManifest.xml. What am i doing wrong?
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.transkript">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transkript"
        tools:targetApi="31">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>



    </application>

</manifest>

I'm very new and i'm not sure what's wrong. I have been reading and been seeing that I should only have one root tag, but examples online show that what i have should be correct? Could it be related to my MainActivity file? The xml above is from AndroidManifest.xml
My app is based around recording an audio file, with a button that starts recording and when pressing it again it ends recording. It compiles and runs but then when pressing the button it crashes and the errors i get in Android studio are:
Multiple root tags at line 22
Tag start is not closed at line 22
Multiple root tags at line 23
Top level element is not completed at line 24
Wrong closing tag name at line 26
Wrong closing tag name at line 27
Wrong closing tag name at line 31
Top level element is not completed at line 32
Thanks!
package com.example.transkript;

import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.File;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button recordButton;
private MediaRecorder recorder;
private boolean isRecording = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    recordButton = findViewById(R.id.recordButton);
    recordButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isRecording) {
                stopRecording();
            } else {
                startRecording();
            }
        }
    });
}

private void startRecording() {
    // Create a new MediaRecorder instance
    recorder = new MediaRecorder();

    // Set the audio source to the microphone
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);

    // Set the output format to 3GPP (media recorder will choose the appropriate audio codec)
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);

    // Set the output file path
    recorder.setOutputFile(getFilePath());

    // Set the audio encoder to AMR NB for efficiency
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

    try {
        // Prepare the recorder
        recorder.prepare();

        // Start recording
        recorder.start();

        // Update the UI to reflect the recording state
        isRecording = true;
        recordButton.setText("Stop Recording");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Handle exceptions
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void stopRecording() {
    if (recorder != null) {
        // Stop the recording
        recorder.stop();

        // Release the MediaRecorder object
        recorder.release();
        recorder = null;

        // Update the UI to reflect the recording state
        isRecording = false;
        recordButton.setText("Record");
    }
}

private String getFilePath() {
    // Get the external storage directory
    File externalStorageDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

    // Check if the external storage is available and writable
    if (externalStorageDir == null || !externalStorageDir.canWrite()) {
        Log.e("MainActivity", "External storage is not available or writable.");
        return null;
    }

    // Create a new directory for your app's files
    File appDirectory = new File(externalStorageDir, "MyAppAudioFiles");
    if (!appDirectory.exists()) {
        if (!appDirectory.mkdirs()) {
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Failed to create directory for audio files.");
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a new file in the app's directory
    File audioFile = new File(appDirectory, "myrecording.3gp");

    // Check if the file can be created
    if (!audioFile.exists()) {
        try {
            if (!audioFile.createNewFile()) {
                Log.e("MainActivity", "Failed to create audio file.");
                return null;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Failed to create audio file.", e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Return the absolute path of the file
    return audioFile.getAbsolutePath();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (recorder != null) {
        recorder.release();
        recorder = null;
    }
}
}

Here is the logcat

"It compiles and runs" - if the error were in AndroidManifest.xml this would not be possible.  Examine the logcat for more info like which file is producing the xml error.  If possible, include the code which handles "pressing the button".

@Computable I have included my MainActivity file and a logcat. I have remove the xml tag like the other guy said but it still crashes when pressing the record button. It seems to be a setAudioSource problem. Maybe it has to do with permissions? when running the app it doesnt ask for permission. Thanks!

Correct - look at this for requesting RECORD_AUDIO permissions.  Probably should add it to the button processing or at onCreate and have button initially disabled until permissions granted.  Note the crash has nothing to do with the "xml" messages so that still needs resolving.   Likely the tutorial you are using is dated - the MediaRecorder() constructor is deprecated - you could replace it with MediaRecorder(this).

The XML declaration (not a "tag"),
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

is perfectly fine.
The rest of the XML document is also fine.  It is well-formed and not the source of either the "Multiple root tags" or the "Top level element is not completed" errors.
Check that you've posted the actual file that's causing the error, and check that you've not pruned away the source of the error in the interest of creating a minimal example.
See also
For the posted error messages, see

How to fix error: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed

...but your posted XML is well-formed.

Take out the XML tag.  It's not needed.  The first tag should be the manifest tag.

Manifest files work just fine with the xml tag.

@Computable They're not necessary, and it's complaining about unclosed tags and multiple top level tags.  I'd be willing to bet removing it would fix things.

It's an XML declaration, not a tag, and it's not the source of either of OP's error messages.  (Yes, it is unnecessary as it stands as it's just re-specifying defaults, but it's also not a problem.)
